# Ruby: In-memory Hash-based and thread-safe buffer?

Tags: ruby, thread-safety, queue, buffer

I'm implementing a kind of write/store buffer in a Redis-backed library to squash multiple `hincrby` calls into a single call. The buffer needs to be fully atomic and work across multiple threads.

I'm quite new to dealing with thread-safety, hence; Are there any existing libraries or standardized ways to implement a global Hash-based buffer/queue that works fine in threaded environments?

As an example, the buffer hash would work something like this pseudo code:

```
buffer #=> { :ident1 => { :value_a => 1, :value_b => 4 },
       #     :ident2 => { :value_a => 2, :value_b => 3 } }

buffer[:ident1][:value_a] #=> 1

# saving merges and increments {:value_a => 2} into buffer[:ident1]
save(:ident1, {:value_a => 2})

buffer[:ident1][:value_a] #=> 3
```

The idea is that after X number of `save` calls the buffer is flushed by calling `save` with each item from the buffer.

Comment: A potentially useful non-answer: do you have objective reason (i.e. measurement) to believe that adding a synchronous bottleneck to an asynchronous system will *improve* performance?

Comment: What Ruby version and VM are you planning on running this on? (MRI, JRuby, Rubinius, IronRuby, etc?)

Comment: Rein: The write buffer is intended to reduce the load on the Redis server itself by folding multiple hincrby calls into a single one. We're currently slamming our Redis server with around 25,000 requests per second on average. Around 38k/sec Redis becomes the bottleneck.

Comment: Phrogz: It's intended to go into a gem, so the general idea is that it'll run on MRI 1.8/1.9 and JRuby at least.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, the way that you provide access to a global value in a thread-safe manner is to use the built-in Mutex class:

```
$buffer = {}
$bufflock = Mutex.new

threads = (0..2).map do |i|
  Thread.new do
    puts "Starting Thread #{i}"
    3.times do
      puts "Thread #{i} got: #{$buffer[:foo].inspect}"
      $bufflock.synchronize{ $buffer[:foo] = ($buffer[:foo] || 1) * (i+1) }
      sleep rand
    end
    puts "Ending Thread #{i}"
  end
end
threads.each{ |t| t.join } # Wait for all threads to complete

#=> Starting Thread 0
#=> Thread 0 got: nil
#=> Starting Thread 1
#=> Thread 1 got: 1
#=> Starting Thread 2
#=> Thread 2 got: 2
#=> Thread 1 got: 6
#=> Thread 1 got: 12
#=> Ending Thread 1
#=> Thread 0 got: 24
#=> Thread 2 got: 24
#=> Thread 0 got: 72
#=> Thread 2 got: 72
#=> Ending Thread 0
#=> Ending Thread 2
```

Code inside a [`Mutex#synchronize`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Mutex.html#M001059) block is atomic per thread; one thread cannot go into `$bufflock` until the previous thread is done with the block.

See also: [Pure-Ruby concurrent Hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080993/pure-ruby-concurrent-hash)

Comment: Thanks, using a Mutex/Monitor seems to be the way to go in other words. I wasn't sure if there's any specific best practices to follow, or pitfalls to look out for :)