# RuntimeError: can't add a new key into hash during iteration

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I get a lot of `RuntimeError: can't add a new key into hash during iteration` errors in my rails app, but the stack trace doesn't point anywhere interesting.

https://gist.github.com/tal-moshayov/71e06a83cee236fdedd0

any hint would be highly appreciated

Comment: did you search for similar issues?

Comment: sure, they all originate from user code while in my case the thread has nothing to do with my code. must be a faulty gem?

Comment: I'm a little late to the thread, but do you remember how you got to the bottom of this? facing a very similar issue and my code does not seem to be the cause

Answer (score 0):

**[add a lock to make shared hash thread-safe]**
I faced very similar issue and the problem was that one thread was trying to modify shared object (Hash) while other thread was in the middle of iterating it.
Eventually I sorted it out by adding lock (Mutex) and using own [Pure-Ruby concurrent Hash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40598360/7022062).

**[examine all threads backtraces to find who owns/iterates your hash]**
The problem with the stack trace you get while trying to modify 'busy' hash is that it shows you chain of functions down to the place where you're trying to modify hash, but it does not show who's currently iterating it in parallel (who owns it)! But I found the way to figure that out by printing stack trace for ALL currently running threads. Here's how you do this:

```
# This solution was found in comment by @thedarkone on https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/24627
rescue Object => boom

  # only for your particular exception:
  if boom.message == "can't add a new key into hash during iteration"
    thread_count = 0
    Thread.list.each do |t|
      thread_count += 1
      err_msg += "--- thread #{thread_count} of total #{Thread.list.size} #{t.object_id} backtrace begin \n"
      # Lets see if we are able to pin down the culprit
      # by collecting backtrace for all existing threads:
      err_msg += t.backtrace.join("\n")
      err_msg += "\n---thread #{thread_count} of total #{Thread.list.size} #{t.object_id} backtrace end \n"
    end

    # and just print it somewhere you like:
    $stderr.puts(err_msg)

    raise # always reraise
  end
```

The above code snippet is useful even just for educational purposes as it can show you (like x-ray) how many threads you actually have (versus how many you thought you have - quite often those two are different numbers ;)

see also: [Concurrent::Hash does not lock on method #each](https://github.com/ruby-concurrency/concurrent-ruby/issues/594)